# drop event is not firing properly with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I have a directive which use the dragover and drop event.
I've created a grid where I wan't to drop files (audio clips) inside.
My parent div looks like this

```
<div  id="sequencer-wrapper" DnDClip (dragClips)="onDrag($event)" (dropClips)="onDrop($event)">
...
 <app-clip *ngFor="let clip of clips"></app-clip>
</div>
```

there is a small margin between grid's rectangle and everything works as expected when I point the dragged element to the margin space but when I drop the file inside the clip space the browser reads the file.

I've tried both `preventDefault` and `return false` without a chance. Looks a bit like the children elements doesn't catch the drop event. Any clues.

here is the directive

```
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) public onDragOver = ( ev:DragEvent ) => {

    ev.preventDefault();

    this.fileOver = true;

    this.drag$.emit( ev );

    return false

  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'] ) public onDrop = async ( ev:DragEvent ) => {

    ev.preventDefault();

      if ( ev.dataTransfer ) {

        this.fileOver = false;

        const files = ev.dataTransfer.files || [];

        if ( files.length > 0 ) {

          let clips:DroppedAudio[] = [];

          let length = files.length;
          let completed = 0;

          for ( let i = 0; i <= length; i++ ) {

            try {

              const file = files[ i ];

              const reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onloadend = ( e ) => {

                if ( e.target?.result ) {

                  const audio = <ArrayBuffer>e.target.result;

                  const filename = `${ file.name } ${ file.type }`;

                  clips.push( { filename, audio } );

                  completed++;

                  if ( completed === length ) {

                    this.drop$.emit( { event:ev, files:clips } );

                  }

                }

                e.target?.result

              }

              reader.readAsArrayBuffer( files[ i ] );

          } catch ( e ) {

          }

        }

      }

    }

  }

}
```

ps: Also one thing to notice is that I pass the `event` attribute to a `Subject` in order to work with it inside my components, I've added the `preventDefault` each times I passed the event to a function.

Comment: It's impossible help without know anything about your directive "DnDClip". If you have two `@Ouputs` dragClips and dropClips, see where and when you execute the `this.dropClips.emit();`

Comment: @Eliseo I've added the directive. Feel free to ask for other code.THanks for your interest

Comment: You have: `for (let i = 0; i<= length; i++)`, see that is `for (let i=0; i<length; i++)` -is `<` **not** `<=` (you begin from 0).  I imagine you has `@Output('dragClips') drag$:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>()` and `@Output('dropClips') drop$:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>()`. Check using `console.log()` to know if is execute the emit

Comment: @Eliseo doesn't change the behaviour.any clues?

Comment: @Eliseo the drop event is not even triggering